# graphql schema is not showing in the documentation explorer. It is showing no schema available. But i am importing

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

// I am importing all the node modules required

```
import express from 'express';
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import schema from './graphql';

var app = express();

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP(req => ({
 schema,
 pretty: true,
 graphiql: true
})));
```

// Connect mongo database

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/graphql');
```

// start server

```
var server = app.listen(8080, () => {
 console.log('Listening at port', server.address().port);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('');
 });
```